# Typescript: how to output compile error messages in the VS Output window?

Tags: typescript

By default, when compiling a Typescript file, the VS Output window shows only one message:
Compiling TypeScript...
When some error occur, the message is shown in the compiled Javascript window. Unfortunatelly, my screen is not wide enough so that I have to scroll the Javascript window to see the details. 
Is there anyway to output the error messages in the VS Output window?

My Typescript version is 0.9.0.1 on VS2012.

Best regards,
Zach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and my TypeScript compiler errors appear in the warnings and errors panel. I am using the latest TypeScript for Visual Studio Extension:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=34790

Is your project reasonably old? If so, you might need to change a couple of bits in your project file - let me see your current TypeScript settings from the project file and I'll make some suggestions!

Comment: I opened the .csproj file and search 'typescript', but only found strings like <TypeScriptCompile Include="Scripts\App\app.ts" />. Maybe I need an upgrade. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: do you have an import statement to the TypeScript targets? something like:<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(VSToolsPath)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />